# IF ELSE statement returning a syntax error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, data-analysis

I am trying to make formula for column value autofilling for blank rows in Google Sheets.

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)); B2;  IF(E2=“male”; 0; IF(AND(D2=3; J2>20); 0; 1)))
```

and getting syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

use `"` not `“` `”`:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)); B2;  IF(E2="male"; 0; IF(AND(D2=3; J2>20); 0; 1)))
```

if you intend to drag it down try this in row 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B)); B2:B;  
              IF(E2:E="male"; 0; IF((D2:D=3)*(J2:J>20); 0; 1))))
```